# NestJS implement express POST call with callback

Tags: typescript, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, nestjs

I'm trying to implement NestJS in an existing server which handles voice conversation for Google Assistant. I'm moving from a setup that uses express to NestJS with Controller and Post decorators.

In the previous setup I used express to [handle](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.post.method) the routes and this would call a callback which takes incoming requests and creates the responses of the chatbot. That setup looked like this:

```
app.post("/google", this.googleController.callback);
```

Now I am trying to do the same using NestJS, but I am having trouble to implement the same structure.

```
@Controller("google")
export class GoogleController {

  public callback: IGoogleEndpoint;

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  constructor() {
    this.callback = dialogflow();
    // setup callback
  };

  @Post()
  public Post(@Req() req: Request) {
    return this.callback(req.body);
  };
```

In the previous express setup, the callback would perform mappings on the incoming request, handle it and create a response for the chatbot. This is all done in that callback, because of this I am looking for a solution that would allow me to direct all incoming request directly into the callback.

Would it be possible to create something like this in NestJS?

Comment: What does the callback do? Could you create a service that you call that handles the library's methods?

Comment: I'm afraid that that isn't possible, I can edit some behavior of the callback to create responses for the chatbot, but other things are handled by the library and I do not know of a way to do those things in a service myself.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try doing is sending the `req` and `res` to the library's `callback` method, but the big difference here is how Nest controllers and Express route handlers manage routing. Nest takes control of setting up the normal `(req, res, next) => {})` for the most part (like a traditional route handler), so that's what's currently being passed to `callback` in the Express app. A possible solution *might* be

```js
@Controller("google")
export class GoogleController {

  public callback: IGoogleEndpoint;

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  constructor() {
    this.callback = dialogflow();
    // setup callback
  };

  @Post()
  public Post(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
    return this.callback(req, res);
  };
}
```

Though, you still may need to figure out a way to provide a callback that is meaningful, so that when the library tries to use `next()`, it will still succeed in its call.